# Ideal WCF timeout values?

Tags: .net, silverlight, wcf

I have a Silverlight client that communicates with WCF. The WCF talks to a database and communicates the values to the client.

The Silverlight client polls the WCF service after regular intervals of 2 seconds. It works properly for some time, around 5 minutes and then it is blocked. When I refresh the page, things seem to work fine again...

I was wondering if this has got something to do with the timeouts, because when I changed the timeout values to 20 minutes, the component worked for a longer time until it blocked again.

Can you please help me understand what should be the ideal timeouts in this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: Please... public the code that enable the timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think, the database connection time + database query execution time + approximate code execution time + some reserve(e.g. DNS resolution, ping, etc.) will be the best WCF timeout value. But I will recommend re-check your algorithm and code, timeout doesn't seem the main issue in your applicaiton.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you make the request again 2 seconds after receiving the server response.

The mistake is to make a request every 2 seconds, without waiting for the response of the previous request.